# mvn install running before package

Tags: java-8, ant, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

So I have a parent maven project with a few child modules. All child projects generate jars and have dependencies. As part of the package phase, following are done

1. Compiled jars are copied to a `lib` directory
2. Dependencies are copied to a `extlib` directory
3. A `tar.gz` package is created in the end (I am worried about the order as assembly is done in parent while copy is done in child project poms)

Once packaging is complete, I want to `install` the package on a remote server, so I have then `antrun` plugin which takes care of it, inside install phase.

The problem is that I cannot control the order in which things are done. I would like to keep the responsibilities separate but if I run the command: `mvn clean package install`, it will run the `install` phase first which I think is because it is part of parent pom deployment which is done first. I have to run it in two commands i.e. `mvn clean package` and then `mvn install` to make sure latest is deployed.

Is there anyway to run this `install` phase at the end when packaging is done?

Comment: First doing the assembly in parent is simply wrong because a parent is executed first before all childs. If you like to package some deps into a `.tar.gz` you have to add a supplemental child module which has the dependencies to the parts you would like to add. Apart from that using `mvn clean package install` duplicates several steps... using `mvn clean install` instead... And using `install` to make a deployment to a remote server is a wrong way using Maven. install is intended to install artifacts into local cache and deploy is intended to transfer to remote repo...

Comment: So you mean I should create a child module, add dependency in it for all other modules, and have it only for assembly and installation?

Comment: Yes exactly. That makes a separation of concern; runs the assembly at the correct time...